# How to add dependencies to a kotlin library?

Tags: kotlin, discord

I am trying to build a kotlin library for discord bots, which can be found at https://github.com/TheDrone7/discord-kt , published to jcenter (bintray link - https://bintray.com/thedrone7/discordKt/discord-kt). The library has a few dependencies of it's own as well.

When I add my own library to my test app, the library's dependencies were not installed and I started getting some errors. Is there a way to specify the library's dependencies so that they get automatically installed when a user uses my library?

EDIT: -

So basically my test app's `build.gradle.kts` file's dependencies section is given below

```
dependencies {
    // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.theDrone:discordKt:0.0.1a")

    // Use the Kotlin test library.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

    // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}
```

And my library is dependent on the following packages: -

- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.0
- org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.4.0
- com.beust:klaxon:5.0.5
- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.26

now when I run my test app, it shows gives error that there is no class named `WebSocketClient` which is a part of the `org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.4.0` package and is also the base of my entire library.

When I add the listed packages to my test app's dependencies, it works perfectly fine. So is there a way that I could define in my library that the apps using it will also automatically depend on the packages my library depends on?

Comment: *When I add my own library to my test app, the library's dependencies were not installed and I started getting some errors.* Please be much more precise: how did you "add your own library"? Which precise errors did you get? With which code?

Comment: I said I added it to my **test** app, like I made another kotlin app to test if my library was functioning properly and I added my library to the dependencies of this new app.

Comment: And you di that **how**? Did you just copy the jar file into a lib folder? Did you add it to Maven dependencies? To gradle dependencies? How? Then what code did you write, and what errors did you get?

Comment: I added my library to the gradle build file's dependencies section.

Comment: OK, so let's try with one question at a time. How did you do that? Post **the code**. When asking why you get an error  with some code, the code and the error matter. And you didn't post any of that. Despite me asking it two times already. Three times now.

Comment: No, don't do that. Post the requested, relevant code and the error you get in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared the `Java-WebSocket` library as a dependency of your library using the `implementation` configuration.

This configuration means: I need that for my code to work, but it's an implementation detail and it's thus not part of my public API, so users of my library won't have access to it in their *compile* classpath.

So Gradle, when it generates the pom.xml file for your library, adds `Java-WebSocket` as a *runtime* dependency, and not as a *compile* dependency.

Read the [java-library plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html), which explains all of that in details. Once you have understood it, use `api` instead of `implementation` in your library's build.gradle.kts file for the dependencies that are part of your API, and should thus be compile dependencies and not runtime dependencies:

```
api("org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.4.0")
```